# "Couldn't load private key (not a private key)" When i push my git. No supported authentication method available (server sent: publickey)

Tags: git, github

**"Couldn't load private key (not a private key)"** When I **push** my git. Then show this message { No supported authentication method available (server sent: publickey)}

fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Somehow **delete** my saved public and private keys on my PC. Then I create a new key and clone my repository. Now I couldn't push my git by TortoiseGit.

Comment: Have you added your latest ssh key to your gitserver?

Comment: Yes, I have added the latest ssh key on gitserver

Answer (score 0):

The thing is your PuTTy uses ssh v2 (and it's good) but you key is generated for version 3 probably.

Here the steps to verify:
[image]

[image]

After you click OK, generate a new key and try to upload it. Worked for me.